# Get and compare Password from AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, passwords, android-alertdialog

I am currently trying to make my `SwitchPreference` password protected. When pressing  that preference an `AlertDialog` should appear that asks for a password. The problem is that I don't really know how to get the password from `userinput` and compare it with the set value in the preferences.

I tried it with methods that I commented out, so you are able to see what I tried.

Here is my **PreferencesActivity.java**:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    Preference websitePref = findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_key));
    final SwitchPreference pwPref = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.sperr_key));


   final  AlertDialog.Builder pw = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   final AlertDialog pwD = pw.create();
    pw.setTitle("Authentifikation (Standart:0000)");

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String savedWebsite = sharedPrefs.getString(websitePref.getKey(), "");
    websitePref.setSummary(savedWebsite);

    final EditText password = findViewById(R.string.pwKey);


   //     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("password", 0).edit();
 //     editor.putString("password", "test");
 //     editor.commit(); 

    pwPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o){
            pw.setView(R.layout.pref_pw);
     //       SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("password", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     //       final String pass = pref.getString("password", null);
     //       password.setText(pass);
            if(pwPref.isChecked()){

                   pw.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     //                       if(password.equals(pass)) {

                                pwPref.setChecked(false);
     //                       }else{

     //                       }
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();

            }else{

                pwPref.setChecked(true);

            }
            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

And my **pref_pw.xml**:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@string/pwKey"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Roshaan Farrukh I can now get the AlertDialog without getting errors, but I can't compare the string.

I implemented the SharedPreferences

```
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("password", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("password", "test");
    editor.commit();
```

And I changed my code into this:

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o){

            pw.setView(R.layout.pref_pw);
            final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pref_pw,null,false);
            pw.setView(view);

            final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("password", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final EditText pwKey = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.string.pwKey);
            final String storedPassword = pref.getString("password",null);
            final String editTextPassword = pwKey.getText().toString();

            if(pwPref.isChecked()){

                   pw.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            if(storedPassword.equals(editTextPassword)) {
                                pwPref.setChecked(false);

                            }else{

                            }
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your dialog view using inflator and through that view you can find pwKey Edit text by calling view.findViewById(R.id.pwKey) like this.

```
 View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pref_pw,null,false);
 EditText pwKey=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pwKey);
 pw.setView(view);
```

Now you can compare text in edit text with the text in your shared preference.

Comment: Thank you! At least I don't get a NullPointerException when trying to set the text. The problem I have now is that the AlertDialog appears but no matter what text input I am giving it, it's doing nothing.

Comment: What you are trying? setText or getText?

Comment: You can compare password entered in edit text with you shared preference password like that
String storedPassword=prefs.getString("password", null);
String editTextPassword= pwKey.getText().toString();

if(storedPassword.equals(editTextPassword){
handle success here
}

Comment: I don't know if I implemented it wrong (new code is in the EDIT) and it still doesn't do anything

Comment: Move
 String storedPassword = pref.getString("password",null);
 String editTextPassword = pwKey.getText().toString();
 inside onClick of setPositiveButton, above if(storedPassword.equals(editTextPassword))

Comment: And don't call pw.setView two times, 
remove pw.setView(R.layout.pref_pw);